# Loading view model gives IDataErrorInfo Type not found in cache MVVM light

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have been banging my head against this one for a while.

I have a WPF project using MVVM-Light that suddenly is giving me errors when I try to load a certain view model.

In this project I have a viewmodel locator that defines the view model as follows:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(Function() SimpleIoc.Default)
''all other dependent services are registered before this view model
SimpleIoc.Default.Register(Of ChangeAddViewModel)()

Public ReadOnly Property ChangeAdd_VM() As ChangeAddViewModel
   Get
      Return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(Of ChangeAddViewModel)()
   End Get
End Property
```

Then in "parent" view I call this viewmodel and assign it to a tab:

```
Return _Locator.ChangeAdd_VM
```

When I try and return the above line I get the following error :

> Message = "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
>
> InnerException = {"Type not found in cache:
>   System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo."}
>
> StackTrace = "   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)" &
>   vbCrLf & "   at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)" & vbCrLf ...
>
> TargetSite = {System.Object InvokeMethod(System.Object,
>   System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)}

Notice the **"Type not found in cache: System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo."**

I use the IDataErrorInfo to provide validation to form fields in the views.  I have more than 12 other views with the same set up that are all working.

I have even compared the constructor of the problem viewModel to confirm its dependencies all work:

```
Public Sub New(NavService As Navigation.INavigationService,
    JobService As IJobDataService,
    UserService As IUserService,
    EmployeeService As IEmployeeDataService,
    ClientService As IClientDataService,
    ModelService As IModelService,
    ErrorService As IErrorHandling,
    dialogService As IDataErrorInfo)

    _NavigationService = NavService
    _UserService = UserService
    _ModelService = ModelService
    _errorService = ErrorService
    _employeeService = EmployeeService
    _clientservice = ClientService
    _dialogService = dialogService
```

There are other viewModels in the project with identical constructor dependencies that are working just fine.  Also, all these dependencies are registered before the viewModel is registered in the viewModelLocator

### WHAT I TIRED:

I have looked at other Type not found in cache questions related to MVVM-Light
and I have tried

1. making sure that all projects in solution have reference to system.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo
2. Restarted Visual Studio many times
3. Deleted Obj folder and forced a rebuild of the solution.
4. Tried manually adding IDataErrorInfo to the ViewModelLocator but I couldn't get it to work because I don't have a custom implementation of it and have no class to register to the interface.
5. I reviewed the git history for this file's history of changes, and no changes were made to this file for months, but this problem appeared in the last week.

### QUESTION:

Can someone help me figure out why only one of my views/viewModels gives the error **Type not found in cache: System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo** when being created.

Thanks in advance

J

Comment: Is your `ChangeAdd_VM` property definition the same as shown `ClientAdd_VM`?

Comment: @Mitya I am not sure what you are asking.  There is only one ChangeAdd_VM property in the viewModelLocator and I showed the code in the question for what that property returns

Comment: @J King you showed `ClientAdd_VM` property

Comment: @Mitya the property ClientAdd_VM is of type **ChangeAddViewModel.**  Is this what you mean?  The view model class is **ChangeAddViewModel.** I am still not sure what you mean by your question?

Comment: You wrote `Return _Locator.ChangeAdd_VM`. Is this line that gives you an exception?  If yes please show the definition of `ChangeAdd_VM` property (you showed another property).

Comment: @Mitya you are right, the clientAdd_VM was an error in this question, I have edited my question.  The line that calls the error does indeed call the ChangeAdd_VM in the actual program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake

The following line in the constructor:

```
dialogService As IDataErrorInfo
```

should be:

```
dialogService As IDialogService
```

The error made it so clear, sometimes you get so blind to your own projects